# Get and compare DIV position with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to compare the scroll position with and element position (relative to window top) and when both have the same value, do something (this case `console.log("we are the same")`).

I've tried the following code, but it's not working. I added an image to explain better.

```
if ($('.contenedorbusiness figure').length) {
    $(document).scroll(function(event) {

        var alto_total = $(this).scrollTop();
        var loader_business = $('.loader_business').offset().top;

        if (alto_total  == loader_business.top) {
            console.log(alto_total + " == " + parseInt(loader_business));
        }
    });
}
```

What I want is:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code as well? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kiokotzu/wQ7Dj/

Comment: Updated yours, works now: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wQ7Dj/1/)

Comment: i've found the answer :) , http://jsfiddle.net/wQ7Dj/5/

Comment: Be aware that your solution isn't 100% reliable.

Comment: Code updated: http://jsfiddle.net/wQ7Dj/6/ , but if you change the div.content height, it doesn't work, hope you can help me to improve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this: `alto_total  == loader_business.top` to this: `alto_total  == loader_business`

`.top` is what's stored in the variable, so there's no need to do it in the comparison.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pMYH2/)**

I took out your initial `if` statement, so make sure the code inside is running. You will also notice you can't scroll fast. If you scroll past it without pausing, the alert won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The following is safer. The `==` can miss the mark.

```
$(document).on("scroll", function (event) {
    var alto_total = $(this).scrollTop();
    var loader_business = $('div').offset();
    console.log(alto_total + " == " + loader_business.top);
    if (alto_total >= loader_business.top) {
        alert('tomalo');
        $(document).off("scroll");
    }
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQ7Dj/2/)